# Promise inside promise don't wait Axios finishing

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, axios

I have a trouble. I receive many objects where I mapping them and I make a external consult using axios and save the return, let's the code:

```
   let savedClients = Object.entries(documents).map(personDocument => {
       let [person, document] = personDocument
       documentFormated = document
       documentNumbers = document.replace(/\D/g, '')

       return ConsultDocuments.getResponse(documentNumbers).then(resultScore => { // Calling the axios
           const info = { ...resultScore }
           return Save.saveClient(info)
       })
   })
   Promise.all(savedClients).then(results => {
       console.log(results) // Come only one document, repeted with the total documents passed in map
   })
```

The problem is when it realized the all map first and then make the consults with only the last result many time (the total of documents passed)

This code is legacy and use async/await don't work (serious, if i don't stay here)

I'am tried N ways to make this, and with the libary Q(), it's make the map in correcty order but it's doesn't wait the axios, and all results come with "pending"

Thanks!

Comment: You should declare your variables `let documentFormated` and `let documentNumbers` you are using globals if you don't and they are overwriting each other.

Comment: OMG!!!!!!! THANKS MAN!!!!!!!!!!!